# How to Input secure text in Watch using WatchKit API?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

In my application I want to activate and deactivate emergency and for that I have to input 4 digit PIN code.
I want to keep it as a Secure Text (*) as we using in iOS.
Is there any way to do so using WatchKit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one demo for secure text entry in Apple Watch to accomplish my requirement. I uploaded code to my git account.
Here I sharing link of Project Repo :

https://github.com/sagargondaliya/SecureTextInputForAppleWatch

[image: Input Controller for Apple Watch]

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , watch kit don't have any `TextField` control. The only way to take input from user is via suggested text or dictation  mode or picker. You can use dictation to take 4 digit input from user or create a custom view with numbers like number pads and use that as `PIN` code input screen.